# trace back index error happened when i made a question list/answer list

Tags: python

basically i have made 4 question list and answer list the first one works fine but the next few don't work and come up with a error sometimes the first question is displayed but not the others

this is the tool and my code https://repl.it/@alandtic/final

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 155, in 
    print(question_list2[random_int])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What is your error analysis? Have you debugged the code?

Comment: @anuragal what do you mean do you mean error then it is Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 155, in print(question_list2[random_int]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What I meant is - What do you think, why this error is coming? Have you debugged the code by putting some `print` statements? When this error came what was the length of `question_list2` and what was the value of `random_int`?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of issues within the code. I would suggest go through the code patiently, and keep ironing them out  e.g. Lines 115 117, use user_answer1 instead of user_answer

Comment: which tool are you refffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top_index=top_index-1
```

after deleting a question, you should atleast decrease top index.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jun 14 10:38:13 2019

@author: jainil
"""

import random

print("\033[0;37;40m\n")
print("welcome to soldier to WW1")
print(
    "If you are ready to die for your country then you must learn all the parts of a WW1 soldier. but first maggot answers a few personal questions. ")
first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
middle_name = input("what is your middle name? ")
last_name = input("what is your last name? ")
full_name = (first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name)
print("Is this your correct name? " + full_name)
yes_or_no = input("Y/N ")

if yes_or_no == ("N"):
    print("program will give you chance to renter name in do not mess up again this is your LAST chance")
    first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
    middle_name = input("what is your middle name? ")
    last_name = input("what is your last name? ")
    full_name = (first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name)
    print("this is your NAME NOW " + full_name)

print("before we get to the training base do you want basic info on how it works. ")
TRAINING = input("Y/N ")

if TRAINING == ("Y"):
    print(
        " welcome to basic training let’s go over basic need to know info? A typical day starts with Reveille (a bugle or trumpet call to wake the soldiers and call them to duty) at 5.30 a.m. After tidying up and cleaning your quarters and having a brew, at 6.30 recruits will parade for an hour and a half to work on your fitness. After breakfast at 8, the morning was spent drilling on the parade square, learning, for instance, to march, form fours and about turn . Between 12.15 and 2 p.m. troops men took lunch before returning for more drill in the afternoon until 4.15. The unlucky image you might be working parties the rafter, but otherwise recruits are off duty, although you might have to spend time cleaning kit and shining boots. In large garrison towns like Aldershot, you can have leisure facilities in the shape of the ‘Smith-Dorrien Soldiers’ Home’, with a billiards room, a library, recreation rooms, private baths and a buffet. ")

i_am_gay = input("are you ready for the test Y/N")

if i_am_gay == ("Y"):
    import random

    question_list = []

    question_list.append("what time do you wake up? ")
    question_list.append("what do you do at 6:30? ")
    question_list.append("what is at Aldershot? ")
    question_list.append("what time do you have lunch? ")
    question_list.append("Do you need to go to bed at a specific time? ")

    answer_list = []

    answer_list.append("5:30")
    answer_list.append("parade")
    answer_list.append("Leasure")
    answer_list.append("12:15")
    answer_list.append("No")

    top_index = 4
    correct = 0

    for i in range(0, 5):

        random_int = random.randint(0, top_index)

        print(question_list[random_int])



        user_answer = input("enter your answer: ")

        if user_answer == answer_list[random_int]:
            print("\033[1;32;40m good job  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m\n")
            correct = correct + 1
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m incorrect  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m \n")
        del question_list[random_int]
        del answer_list[random_int]
        top_index=top_index-1

    print("you scored " + str(
        correct) + " out of 5 based on this you will receive a rank all scores are collected to give you a final rank at the end of our testing. ")

import os
import time

time.sleep(10)
os.system('clear')

print(
    "The next step of your training is to chose a group to learn more about and train in all with different types ways to train. first is infantry (multiple choice questions) second is planing (tactics questions) and finally is marine (fill in the blank)")
form = input("please select which one you want 1/2/3 ")

if form == ("1"):
    form = input("you have selected infantry is this correct if yes enter Y1 if no then put in your  teams number")

if form == ("Y1"):
    print(
        "first step is to train you on the role of infantry. your main mission is to be a ground troop this includes but is not limited to. building trenches, fighting off front lines and attack the enemies trenches.")

    print(
        "now that your training is complete time for your first quiz this will be multiple choice and will be the main for your rank. ")

    question_list1 = []

    question_list1.append(
        "which one of these is not your job? A: build trench B: act as a spy C: fight on the front lines D: follow orders ")
    question_list1.append("who is your boss? A: the furrier B: privates C: civilians D: a lieutenant ")
    question_list1.append("which weaponry is better for long range A:50 cow  B: mp5  C: benelli M3  D: Barret M82 ")
    question_list1.append(
        "which is not a rank? A: master first sergeant B: command segment major C: corporeal:  D: private ")

    answer_list1 = []

    answer_list1.append("B")
    answer_list1.append("D")
    answer_list1.append("D")
    answer_list1.append("A")

    top_index1 = 3
    correct = 0

    for i in range(0, 4):

        random1_int = random.randint(0, top_index1)

        print(question_list1[random1_int])



        user_answer1 = input("enter [A] [B] [C] [D] : ")

        if user_answer == answer_list1[random1_int]:
            print("\033[1;32;40m good job  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m\n")
            correct = correct + 2
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m incorrect  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m \n")
        del question_list1[random1_int]
        del answer_list1[random1_int]
        top_index1 = top_index1 - 1

if form == ("2"):
    form = input("you have selected planing is this correct if yes enter Y2 if no then put in your  teams number")

if form == ("Y2"):
    print(
        "first step is to train you on the role of a planer. you need to give tips and info to your troops based on you skills. ")

    print(
        "now that your training is complete time for your first quiz this will be a tactics question and will be the main determination for your rank. ")

    question_list2 = []

    question_list2.append(
        "side X has a large compound with 12 men and side + has the element of surprise and 3 elite troops  ")
    question_list2.append("side X has 3 troops and the high ground side + has 13 troops but is on the low ground ")

    answer_list2 = []

    answer_list2.append("x")
    answer_list2.append("+")

    top_index2 = 1
    correct = 0

    for i in range(0, 2):

        random_int = random.randint(0, top_index2)

        print(question_list2[random_int])



        user_answer2 = input("which side has the advantage x or +? ")

        if user_answer2 == answer_list2[random_int]:
            print("\033[1;32;40m good job  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m\n")
            correct = correct + 4
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m incorrect  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m \n")

        del question_list2[random_int]
        del answer_list2[random_int]
        top_index2 = top_index2 - 1

if form == ("3"):
    form = input("you have selected marine is this correct if yes enter Y3 if no then put in your teams number")

if form == ("Y3"):
    print(
        "first step is to train you on the role of a marine. you need to give tips and info to your troops based on you skills. ")

    print(
        "now that your training is complete time for your first quiz this will be fill in the blanks and will be the main determination for your rank. ")

    question_list3 = []

    question_list3.append(" the marines are ___ based operatives  ")
    question_list3.append(" for under water travel marines use _____ ")
    question_list3.append(" the average marine trains for _ weeks ")

    answer_list3 = []

    answer_list3.append("sea")
    answer_list3.append("submarines")
    answer_list3.append("13")

    top_index3 = 2
    correct = 0

    for i in range(0, 3):

        random_inte = random.randint(0, top_index3)

        print(question_list3[random_inte])



        user_answer3 = input("fill in the blank with the correct word ")

        if user_answer3 == answer_list3[random_inte]:
            print("\033[1;32;40m good job  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m\n")
            correct = correct + 3
        else:
            print("\033[1;31;40m incorrect  \n")
            print("\033[0;37;40m \n")

        del question_list3[random_inte]
        del answer_list3[random_inte]
        top_index3 = top_index3 - 1

time.sleep(10)
os.system('clear')

print(
    "congratulations on your finishing of the course i will now give you a rank based on your score from e1(private) to e9(major) ")

if correct == (1):
    print("e1 i would say not bad but that should be a lie")
elif correct == (2):
    print("e1 i would say not bad but that should be a lie")
elif correct == (3):
    print("e2 not worthless but not good")
elif correct == (4):
    print("e2 not worthless but not good")
elif correct == (5):
    print("e3 now i will make a man out of you")
elif correct == (6):
    print("e3 now i will make a man out of you")
elif correct == (7):
    print("e4 seems like front lines will be wasted on you")
elif correct == (8):
    print("e5 good job mr wane")
elif correct == (9):
    print("e6 no front line for you")
elif correct == (10):
    print("e7 steve rogers would be proud")
elif correct == (11):
    print("e8 welcome to the order")
elif correct == (12):
    print("e9 no jokes you did very good my superior")
elif correct == (13):
    print("you have no rank you scored 100% my bet is your cheater shame on you. ")
elif correct == (14):
    print("this is a marine exclusive rank i added because i was lazy tbh. ")
```

you have not updated top index even,